Show that $\lim\limits_{(x,t)\to(x_0,0)}\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-xt}}{t}$ exists

Show that $\lim\limits_{(x,t)\to(x_0,0)}\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-xt}}{t}$ exists, where $x_0$ is some arbitrary but fixed point with $x_0>0$ and $t\in\mathopen]0,\infty\mathclose[$.

If we only looked at $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-x_0t}}{t}$ and assume some fixed $x_0>0$, then we can simply prove it by L'Hospital's theorem which delivers $x_0-1$.
But how do I show it if I consider the two dimensional limit $\lim\limits_{(x,t)\to(x_0,0)}$?
Intuitively the limit should also be $x-1$ and I tried to use Taylor expansion to find some suitable bounds:
$$
\left|\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-xt}}{t}\right|=\frac{e^{-xt}-e^{-t}}{t}\leq\frac{1}{t+xt^2}-e^{-t}\frac{1}{t}.
$$
But this gets me nowhere. Any ideas or hints which way to go?

I think that your $t$ should be in $\mathopen]0, \infty\mathclose[$, not $[0, \infty\mathclose[$.  (Note, by the way, that this will not TeX well if typeset as obvious: $t \in ]0, \infty[$ t \in ]0, \infty[.  You can tame it by giving explicit \mathopen and \mathclose instructions: $t \in \mathopen]0, \infty\mathclose[$ t \in \mathopen]0, \infty\mathclose[.)

By Lagrange mean value theorem, there exists $\xi=\xi(x,t)$ between $-1$ and $-x$ s.t.
$$e^{-t}-e^{-xt}=(x-1)te^{\xi t}.$$
Hence $\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-xt}}{t}=(x-1)e^{\xi t}$.
Now let $x\rightarrow x_0$, $t\rightarrow 0$. We have
$$(x-1)e^{\xi t}\rightarrow x_0-1.$$
This is because $\xi$ is between $-1$ and $-x$, hence bounded.

We have $$\lim_{(x, t) \to (x_0, 0)} \frac{e^{-t} - e^{-xt}}t - (x - 1) = \lim_{(x, t) \to (x_0, 0)} \frac{e^{-t} + t - 1}t - x\frac{e^{-x t} + x t - 1}{x t} = \lim_{(x, t) \to (x_0, 0)} F(t) - x F(x t),$$ where $F$ is the one-variable function on $\mathbb R$ given by $$F(z) = \begin{cases} \frac{e^{-z} + z - 1}z, & z \ne 0 \\ 0, & z = 0. \end{cases}$$  Since $F$ is continuous, the limit is $F(0) - x_0 F(0) = 0$, as expected.

Can you explain why the first equation holds; it seems that the multiplication with $(-1)$ is wrong, and why $F$ is continuous at $z=0$?

@Philipp, re, yes, thank you, you are right; I made a sign error.  I have fixed it now.

It also seems that your function $F$ doesn't work though the idea is correct. Try $F(z):=\frac{e^{-z}+z-1}{z}$ if $z>0$ and $0$ if $z=0$.

@Philipp, re, yes, of course you are right.  My apologies for my sloppiness.  I have fixed this, too.

Just to make sure to fully understand your reasoning: What you have shown is $\lim_{(x, t) \to (x_0, 0)} \frac{e^{-t} - e^{-xt}}t - (x - 1)=0$. Further, we immediately see that $\lim_{(x, t) \to (x_0, 0)} (x - 1)=x_0-1$. Both together delivers $$\lim_{(x, t) \to (x_0, 0)} \left(\frac{e^{-t} - e^{-xt}}t - (x - 1)+(x-1)\right)=\lim_{(x, t) \to (x_0, 0)} \frac{e^{-t} - e^{-xt}}t - (x - 1)+\lim_{(x, t) \to (x_0, 0)}(x-1)=x_0-1.$$

@Philipp, re, yes, exactly.

I am going to prove that the limit $\lim\limits_{(x,t)\to(x_0,0)}\dfrac{e^{-t}-e^{-xt}}t\;$ exists and I will also get its value by using the following notable limit:
$\lim\limits_{u\to0}\dfrac{e^u-1}u=1\,.$
It results that
$\!\!\!\!\!\!\lim\limits_{(x,t)\to(x_0,0)}\!\!\!\dfrac{e^{-t}-e^{-xt}}t=\!\!\!\!\!\lim\limits_{(x,t)\to(x_0,0)}\!\left[e^{-xt}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{e^{t(x-1)}-1}{t(x-1)}\!\cdot\!(x-1)\right]\!=$
$\!\!\!\!\!\!\underset{\color{blue}{\overbrace{\,\text{ by letting }u=t(x-1)\;}}}{\mathbf{=}}\lim\limits_{(x,t)\to(x_0,0)}\!\!\!\!e^{-xt}\cdot\lim\limits_{u\to0}\dfrac{e^u-1}u\cdot\!\!\!\!\!\!\lim\limits_{(x,t)\to(x_0,0)}(x-1)\!=$
$\quad=1\cdot1\cdot(x_0-1)=x_0-1$
